# Introduction to Data Types

Tags: c

I just started learning C and copied this directly from a book. Can someone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int     integerVar = 100;
    float   floatingVar = 331.79;
    double  doubleVar = 8.44e+11;
    char    charVar = "W";

    _Bool   boolVar = 0;

    printf ("integerVar = %i\n", integerVar);
    printf ("floatingVar = %f\n", floatingVar);
    printf ("doubleVar = %e\n", doubleVar);
    printf ("doubleVar = %g\n", doubleVar);
    printf ("charVar = %c\n", charVar);

    printf ("boolVar = %i\n", boolVar);

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
datatypes.c: In function ‘main’:
datatypes.c:8: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem here:

```
char    charVar = "W";
```

you probably meant:

```
char    charVar = 'W';
```

`"W"` is a string. `'W'` is a char. The latter is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `'w'` not `"w"`. The latter one is a zero-terminated string, i.e. it's a pointer to a char array.

Answer (score 3):

`"W"` is not a char but a string constant. What you want is `'W'`.

And a string constant is a pointer to a chararacter array (in this case, `{ 'W', 0 }`), hence the warning: "initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast".

Here, "integer" is meant to be understood as any integer type (char, short, int, long, long long for compilers defining it, and their unsigned variants, and their numerous typedefs...)

Answer (score 2):

`"W"` represents a `char*`, or C-string.
`'W'` represents a `char`, or a single, 1-byte character, and is what you want.

The single/double quotes are what distinguishes the two.

Answer (score 1):

The line `char charVar="W";`
is not correct in this example because "W" is a string and is being treated as a pointer to an array of characters.  Change this to `'W'` to make this a character.

Answer (score 0):

In C, there's a difference between strings and chars. In fact, strings are sequences of characters, defined as `char[length]` or even `char*` (variable length). Because it's multiple `char`s, it requires a "pointer" (don't worry, I won't explain).

For the C compiler to know the difference between a char and a string it invented two styles of quotes: single and double quotes. A `char` uses a single quotes (`'W'`) and a string uses double quotes (`"W"`).

You can declare a string like this :

```
char* myString = "this is a string";
```

While a single char is declared like this :

```
char charVar = 'W';
```

Bottom line: a string is a sequence of `char`s, and defined with double quotes. A single char is defined with single quotes.